# How can I get the original resource in ngResource with a responseError interceptor?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am doing some caching of original (pre-send) and new (post-send) data on an ngResource. I am using `$resource` interceptor for `response` and `responseError`.

Here is the problem: in `response`, the argument has a property `resource`, which allows me to manipulate the resource before passing it back to the caller.

In `responseError`, there is no such property, so how do I manipulate the resource?

Code sample:

```
              update: { method: 'put', isArray: false, interceptor: {
                    response: function (response) {
                        // clear my pristine cache 
                        // I have access to response.resource
                        angular.copy(pristineData,response.resource);
                        return(response);
                    },
                    responseError: function (response) {
                                                    // the PUT failed, I want to reset the data
                        // need to reset the data to pristine
                        // "pristineData" is cached elsewhere
                        // HOW DO I DO THIS, SINCE response.resource UNAVAILABLE?
                        angular.extend(response.resource,pristineData);
                    }
                }},
```

Comment: I am not sure but, you can directly try to access the resource variable that defines the update method in the responseError.

Comment: @chandermani, you lost me?

Comment: `var r= $resource("url", { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT',interceptor:{ responseError:function(response) { //try to access r here directly. } } } })`

Comment: Oh, I see. But that would give the class, not the instance. If you prefer, it would give the static `User` (on which I could call `new User({name:"chandermani")` and not the instance given by `var u = new User({name:"chandermani"); u.$update();` It is inside the `u.$update()` that I am trying to intercept.

Comment: Right, i understand that now.

Comment: I sort of found a way to hack around it by changing the prototype, so I can catch `this`, but it is messy.

Comment: Add it as solution, maybe someone can suggest something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no really good answer, so here is what I did.

I created my own `$save` which called either `$create` or `$update`, and then used promise handlers to do the changes.

```
        factory('Resource',['$resource','_','$q',function ($resource,_,$q) {
        return function(url,params,methods){
            var defaults = {
              update: { method: 'put', isArray: false, interceptor: {
                    response: function (response) {
                        // do pristine cache setting here
                        return(response);
                    }
                }},
              create: { method: 'post',interceptor: {
                    response: function (response) {
                        // do pristine cache setting here
                        return(response);
                    }
              }},
            }, resource = $resource(url,params,angular.extend(defaults,methods));

            // need to change $save *after* creating $resource
            resource.prototype.$save = function() {
                var that = this;
                return this.id ? this.$update.apply(this,arguments).then(null,function (result) {
                    // reset from pristine cache here
                }) : this.$create.apply(this,arguments);
            };
    }]);
```